# Why the serialize behavior is difference in simulator and iPad device in monotouch?

Tags: serialization, xamarin.ios

Why the serialize behavior is difference in simulator and iPad device in monotouch?
I have declare the serialize behavior is UTF-8, but when send the serialize data from ipad device to WCF service, I  trace the message, it change to ascii, why?  (and in simulator it's OK with UTF-8)

trace in simulator/Chinese Language: 
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? >
...

trace in iPad device/Chinese Language: 
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"? >
...

btw, I serialize the data manually with my static method: XmlSerialize.

```
    public static string XmlSerialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }


    public static T XmlDeserialize<T>(string xmlOfObject) where T : class
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sr.Write(xmlOfObject);
                sr.Flush();
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return serializer.Deserialize(ms) as T;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup `XmlSerializer` to use utf-8 as well:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.path"))
{
  using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = false, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
  {
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myObject);
  }
}
```

Otherwise it will use the default encoding, whatever that happens to be.

Comment: hi, in my project, i have been setup the xmlserializer to use utf-8: using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
and using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))

Comment: I'm guessing you got it working? (Sorry just now saw your comment) Yeah I know it's weird that `XmlWriterSettings` are required for it to work right.